# Whether the lower limit topology can be the weak topology for a family of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology

For the following question, I think the answer is the lower limit topology as the weak topology.  I am not sure how to go about showing it.  also, do I have to consider the fact that the lower limit topology is finer than the usual topology, because the weak topology is suppose to be the smallest topology which makes a family of functions not only continuous but a particular type of continuiuty, being right continuous. I don't think the usual topology would satisfy it.

The question is as follows: a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be continuous from the right or right continuous for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x) = f(a).$ Find the weak topology on the domain set $\mathbb{R}$, determined by the collection of all right continuous functions on it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any Tychonoff space has the weak topology wrt its own set of continuous real-valued functions. This is a standard fact. So $f$ is right continuous everywhere iff $f$ is continuous as a map from the lower limit to the usual topology is enough, as the lower limit topology is Tychonoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define the continuous from the right at $a \in \Bbb R$ condition for $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as follows:

$$\forall \varepsilon>0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: (x>a \land |x-a| < \delta) \to |f(x)-f(a)| < \varepsilon\tag{1}$$

which is I think pretty standard. Let the smallest topology that makes all the functions that are continuous from the right at every point, continuous, be called $\mathcal{T}_w$

Then if $f: (\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_l) \to (\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_e)$ (from lower limit topology to Euclidean topology) is continuous, then $f$ fulfills $(1)$ at all points:

Having $a$ and $\varepsilon >0$ arbitrary, $f^{-1}[(f(a)-\varepsilon, f(a)+\varepsilon)]$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_l$ (by continuity of $f$, and the fact that open intervals are open in $\mathcal{T}_e$) and contains $a$, so there is some $\delta>0$ such that $$[a,a+\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}[(f(a)-\varepsilon, f(a)+\varepsilon)]$$ which immediately implies $(1)$ by definition.

On the other hand if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on the right at every point, we have that $f$ seen as a function from $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_l)$ to $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_e)$ is continuous: let $O$ be open in the Euclidean topology and let $a \in f^{-1}[O]$; we need to show that $a$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}[O]$. First note that $f(a) \in O$ and $O$ is Euclidean open so there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(f(a)-\varepsilon, f(a)+\varepsilon) \subseteq O$. Apply $(1)$ to $a$ and this $\varepsilon$ and the condition gives that $x \in [a,a+\delta)$ implies that $f(x) \in (f(a)-\varepsilon, f(a)+\varepsilon)$, or equivalently $$[a,a+\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}[(f(a)-\varepsilon, f(a)+\varepsilon)] \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$$ showing that indeed $a$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}[O]$, as required. So $f^{-1}[O]$ is lower-limit open and $f$ is continuous.

Now $\mathcal{T}_l$ is *one* topology on $\Bbb R$ that makes all right-continuous $f$ continuous, and $\mathcal{T}_w$ is the minimal such, so $$\mathcal{T}_w \subseteq \mathcal{T}_l$$ And if $\mathcal{T}$ is any topology such that all right continuous $f$ are continuous when seen as $f(\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}) \to (\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_e)$ then $\mathcal{T}_l \subseteq \mathcal{T}$: let $[a,b)$ be a basic open set of the lower limit topology, then the function $\chi: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $\chi(x)=1$ if $x \in [a,b)$ and $\chi(x)=0$ otherwise, is continuous from the right at any point. This is easy to check by the definition $(1)$. Now, as $\chi$ thus is continuous with domain $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T})$ we know that $[a,b) = \chi^{-1}(\frac12, \rightarrow)] \in \mathcal{T}$ and so $\mathcal{T}$ contains all basic open sets of $\mathcal{T}_l$, so $\mathcal{T}_l \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. This shows directly that $\mathcal{T}_l$ is the minimal topology that makes all right continuous functions continuous.

Comment: thank you for showing me how to solve the problem.  I actually have not learn what a Tychonoff space is.  I was thinking along the lines of continuous functions that are right continuous and what kind of topology their inverse image can be made into and then whether such a topology is the smallest topology.   I think I still has a very weak understanding of weak and quotient topology at this point.

Comment: @SethMai I don't use the concept of Tychonoff space in this proof. The main points are: the lower limit topology makes all right-continuous functions continuous and if a topology does that it has to contains all sets $[a,b)$. These two facts are enough.

Comment: I don't have to worry about the usual topology is coarser than the lower limit topology.  I mean can't the usual topology make all right continuous functions continuous also?

Comment: @SethMai No, it cannot, as $\chi$ (for $[0,1)$ say) is not continuous for the usual topology but it *is* right continuous.

Comment: ah ok ok.   Thank you for clarifying that up.

Comment: I have another question.  I know that a topology can have many different bases, and any particular base generates a unique topology.  If we are given a family of functions in terms of inverse images. We want to find a topology that would make such family of function continuous with a specific type of continuity.  Is it possible then to have more than one topologies that could satisfy the particular condition for continuity.  If so, to decide which one of these topologies is the correct one.  All I have to do is to find the smallest topology amongst these different topologies?

Comment: @SethMai given a set of functions on $X$ there will be many topologies in general that make those functions continuous (I assume that the codomains have a topology already) e.g. the discrete topology always works. But there is a *unique* minimal topology that will do it. It’s called the initial (or weak) topology wrt this set of functions.